# Flask python ошибка errno 111

Tags: python, post, flask

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from collections import namedtuple

from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request
import time


app = Flask(__name__)
i=0
Message = []

messages = [0,0,0,0]


@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def hello_world():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/main', methods=['GET'])
def main():
    return render_template('main.html', messages=messages)


@app.route('/ajax', methods=['GET'])
def ajax():
    return render_template('load.html', messages=messages)

@app.route('/1', methods=['GET'])
def content():
    return render_template('1.html', messages=messages)


@app.route('/add_message', methods=['POST'])
def add_message():
    messages.clear()
    time.sleep(1)
    name1 = request.form["name1"]
    name2 = request.form["name2"]
    name3 = request.form["name3"]
    name4 = request.form["name4"]
    messages.append(name1)
    messages.append(name2)
    messages.append(name3)
    messages.append(name4)
    return redirect(url_for("main"))
```

Проблема: не принимает POST запросы по ссылке add_message. Выводит:

> requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /add_message (Caused by NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

Код POST запроса:
import requests

```
name1='vasya21'
name2='dima'
name3='luci'
name4='vanya'
r = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/add_message',data={'name1':name1,'name2':name2,'name3':name3,'name4':name4})
```

Ставил по инструкции https://www.8host.com/blog/razvyortyvanie-prilozheniya-flask-na-servere-ubuntu/

apache2 config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName mywebsite.com
ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
<Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static
<Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/FlaskApp/static/>
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
LogLevel warn
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

wsgi config

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/")
from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key =
```

[image: Curl check]

Comment: На локальной машине все работает окей, это проблема на сервере (apache2)

Comment: Значит расскажите, как весь этот код запускается на сервере

Comment: Запускается нормально, т.е. все страницы запускает. Затем, на странице 'main' есть форма, которая отправляет пост запрос на адрес add_message, который должен обрабатывать flask (запрос), затем перенаправлять обратно на страницу 'main'.

Comment: «нормально» — это не ответ. Файлы конфигурации апача и всего остального связанного с проблемой в студию

Comment: Потому что надо было помещать не в коммент, а в текст вопроса.

Comment: Из конфигурации отчётливо видно, что апач работает на порту 80, а вы вместо этого зачем-то ломитесь в порт 5000, на котором естественно никто не работает — оттого и ошибка, очевидно

Comment: Спасибо, теперь внутри серва пост заработал (отправляю скриптом внутри сервера). Но если пытаюсь через браузер, ошибка.Добавил в пост скрин курла.

Comment: Не менее очевидно, что нужно отправлять POST-запрос (вы сами это прописали в коде Flask-приложения), а вы через curl отправили GET

Comment: The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.

Пробнул с сервиса http://seriyps.ru/postget/. В curl ничего не изменилось.

Comment: Читайте текст ошибки в логах сервера, больше тут ничего ответить

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь. Раз внутри сервака теперь отправляет, значит и с внешними можно решить=).

Comment: Окей. Лог показывает, что запущен питон 2.7. А на сервере я кодил на питоне 3.6. В логах сервера идут ошибки синтаксиса. Продолжаю изыскания.